# SQLite3 table not saving correctly

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlite

I have recently been working on a login database project, and have come across a problem: the table doesn't save properly.

I have the code

```
def change_password(username, password):
    while 1:
        new_pass = input("Enter new password:\n")
        if not new_pass:
            print("Cancelled")
            raise SystemExit()

        if new_pass == password:
            print("That's already your password.")
        elif len(new_pass) < 6:
            print("Password must be at least 6 characters")
        else:
            break

    cursor.execute("""UPDATE logins SET password = ? WHERE username = ?""", (new_pass, username))

    date_time = dt.now()
    time = date_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    date = date_time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

    cursor.execute("""UPDATE logins SET changepass_date = ? WHERE username = ?""", (date, username))
    cursor.execute("""UPDATE logins SET changepass_time = ? WHERE username = ?""", (time, username))
    db.commit()
```

which works exactly as expected (updates `password`, `changepass_date` and `changepass_time`).

However I also have the code

```
def change_username(username):
    while 1:
        new_username = input("Enter new username:\n")
        if not new_username:
            print("Cancelled")
            raise SystemExit()

        if new_username == username:
            print("That's already your username")
        elif len(new_username) < 6:
            print("Username must be at least 6 characters")
        else:
            break

    try:
        cursor.execute("""UPDATE logins SET username = ? WHERE username = ?""", (new_username, username))
        date_time = dt.now()
        time = date_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        date = date_time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

        cursor.execute("""UPDATE logins SET changeuser_date = ? WHERE username = ?""", (date, username))  # doesn't work
        cursor.execute("""UPDATE logins SET changeuser_time = ? WHERE username = ?""", (time, username))  # doesn't work
        db.commit()

        print("Successfully changed your username to '{}'".format(new_username))
    except sql.IntegrityError:
        print("That username is already taken")
        change_username(username)
```

which doesn't work as expected (it only saves `username`, not `changeuser_date` or `changeuser_time`).
I have spent many hours researching this and came across different pages on StackOverflow, however, it was because there was no commit - which I have (`db.commit()`).

The code I have for creating the table is

```
cursor.execute(
    '''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS logins(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY unique,
        username TEXT unique,
        password TEXT,
        admin BOOLEAN,
        created_date TEXT,
        created_time TEXT,
        recent_date TEXT,
        recent_time TEXT,
        changepass_date TEXT,
        changepass_time TEXT,
        changeuser_date TEXT,
        changeuser_time TEXT)
    ''')
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

By the time you try to update the date and time, the username has already changed, so your UPDATE statement does not find any rows that have the old `username`.

In the statement that doesn't work, pass `new_username` instead of `username` to the WHERE clause of the UPDATE statement.

---

Furthermore, you could improve it and reduce the 3 queries into 1:

```
cursor.execute(
    """
    UPDATE logins
      SET (username = ?, changeuser_date = ?, changeuser_time = ?)
      WHERE username = ?
    """,
    (new_username, date, time, username))
```

Same goes for the password updates:

```
cursor.execute(
    """
    UPDATE logins
      SET (password = ?, changepass_date = ?, changepass_time = ?)
      WHERE username = ?
    """,
    (new_pass, date, time, username))
```